# WCF Transparent Proxy without specifying endpoint address on ChannelFactory

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, proxy

I've configured a WCF Service and I'm using a transparent proxy in another assembly using Channel Factory. The problem I'm facing is: On the constructor of the channel factory, I have to manually specify the endpoint address name for the service to work, when it should find the address by just using the interface of the service. what am I doing wrong here?

Heres the code:

Service Config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfTestService.Service1" behaviorConfiguration= "ServiceBehavior">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="Contracts.DataContract.IService1">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https"/>
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Proxy Config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IService1" />
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost/WCFTestService/Service1.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IService1" contract="Contracts.DataContract.IService1"
        name="WcfTestService.Service1">
        <identity>
          <dns value="localhost" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Proxy that works, specifying endpoint name:

```
public class Service1Proxy : IService1
    {
        private IService1 service;

        public Service1Proxy() {
            service = new ChannelFactory<IService1>("WcfTestService.Service1").CreateChannel();
        }

        public string GetData(int value)
        {
            return service.GetData(value);
        }

        public CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite)
        {
            return service.GetDataUsingDataContract(composite);
        }
    }
```

The proxy that throws an exception:

```
public class Service1Proxy : IService1
    {
        private IService1 service;

        public Service1Proxy() {
            service = new ChannelFactory<IService1>().CreateChannel();
        }

        public string GetData(int value)
        {
            return service.GetData(value);
        }

        public CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite)
        {
            return service.GetDataUsingDataContract(composite);
        }
    }
```

With this last code block, the channel factory throws the following exception:

The Address property on ChannelFactory.Endpoint was null.  The ChannelFactory's Endpoint must have a valid Address specified.

I thought it could create the service just by the interface, but that doens't seem to work, I have to specify the endpoint name "WcfTestService.Service1". some co-workers said that it's possible, but none could show me how.

I appreciate any insights.

Comment: I don't think you can do it without specifying the address somehow.  How would the `ChannelFactory` know what address to use?  You could (conceivably) have multiple client endpoints in the config file - it's not going to choose one at random.  All the interface does is define the service contract - it says nothing about the address where the service is (and it shouldn't).

Comment: But thats exactly what it should do. It's not supposed to choose at random, it is supposed to coose based on the service contract, which is declared in the endpoint. If my ChannelFactory creates the channel for the ITestService service contract, it should look in the client config for the endpoint which the ITestService contract